# Random character string as output

Tags: python, for-loop

I’m trying to write code that draws a random synonym from a list.
Instead of that, I’m getting a random string of characters that seem to bear no relation to any of my code.

Here’s the main module code:

```
from output import *
import definitions
from responses import *

…

def respond(wordList):
    output = ""
    for word in wordList:
        output = (output + " " + (random.choice(word)))
    return output

def edison():
    mood = ask("Hi, " + username + "! How are you today? ")
    if mood.lower() in definitions.positive:
        print(respond(['i_am', 'happy', 'to' 'hear', 'that']) + "!")
    elif mood.lower() in definitions.negative:
        print(respond(['i_am', 'sorry_unhappy', 'to' 'hear', 'that']) + "!")

…

edison()
```

Here’s the code for responses.py:

```
i_am = ["I am", "I'm"]
happy = ["cheerful", "delighted", "glad", "joyful", "joyous", "overjoyed", "pleased", "thrilled", "gleeful", "happy"]
sorry_unhappy = ["sorry"]
to = ["to"]
hear = ["listen to", "hear"]
that = ["that"]
```

Here’s a sample of my output:

```
Hi, Test User! How are you today? bad
 m _ h h!
```

Comment: you're feeding strings - e.g. `'i_am'` - to the `respond` method rather than variables - e.g. `i_am`. Remove the superfluous apostrophes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You weren't using the built in responses from `responses.py' but a fixed str response

Replace `edison` with:

```
def edison():
    mood = ask("Hi, " + username + "! How are you today? ")
    if mood.lower() in definitions.positive:
        print(respond([i_am, happy, to, hear, that]) + "!")
    elif mood.lower() in definitions.negative:
       print(respond([i_am, sorry_unhappy, to, hear, that]) + "!")
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is likely `random.choice(word)`. word is an element of `wordList`, and a random choice from a string chooses a random letter. Try `random.choice(wordList)` instead.

If you want to concatenate the wordList as output, since it looks somehow like a sentence already, you could do this:

```
output = " ".join(wordList)
```